# React Text editor AI typeahead/autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, openai-api, react-quill, editorjs

Is there a way to add a chatGPT like typeahead/auto completion with react Quill or editor js? The one where I can start typing and AI will give me text suggestion from Open AI API which I can append to my text with a tab. Seems like there is no official way to achieve this in these packages.

Answer (score -1):

There is a library available to provide WYSIWYG editor with AI-powered autocompletion. The name of this library is [Novel](https://github.com/steven-tey/novel) which provides notion like editor with autocompletion text using Openai. It's very simple to use in your react component

```
npm i novel
```

Example

```
import Editor from "novel"
export default function App(){
return (
<Editor completionApi="/api/generate" />
  )
}
```

Where **completionAPI** prop is a route (if you are on nextjs) or a serverless cloud function url where you can implement the openai backend service required by your novel Editor component

[Here](https://github.com/steven-tey/novel/blob/main/apps/web/app/api/generate/route.ts) they provide the example of api route in nextjs